# Is there a way to automatically get the shape of feature map and use it to build the graph in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am building my own CNN
Between the convolution layer and fully connect layer
I need to know the size of the output of convolution layer, namely

> width_feature map * height_feature map * number_feature map

so I can know the shape of weighting between this two layer, that is,

> [number_neuron_output of convolution layer , number_neuron_1st fully connect layer].

What I want to do is to get the [width_feature map,height_feature,map*number_feature map]
automatically and can thus use this to build the connection between convolutoin layer and fully connection layer

I tried like

```
def add_convtofully_layer(self,size_out,data_in):
      shape_in=tf.shape(data_in)#[batch,H,W,C]
      data_re=tf.reshape(data_in,[-1,shape_in[1]*shape_in[2]*shape_in[3]])
      W=self.weight_NN(shape_in[1]*shape_in[2]*shape_in[3],size_out)
      B=self.bias_NN(size_out)
      data_drop=tf.nn.dropout(data_re,self.drop)
      result=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(data_drop,W)+B)
      return result

def weight_NN(self,w_in,w_out):
    W=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([w_in,w_out],stddev=0.1),name='weight')
    return W


def bias_NN(self,out):
    B=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0,dtype=tf.float32,shape=[out]),name='bias')
    return B
```

But only got the message

> ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("Fully_connect_layer1/truncated_normal:0", shape=(?, 150), dtype=float32)

Is there a way to use Tensorflow to do this? or the only way is I need to calculate it myself first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input still has a variable batch dimension. (The ? in `shape=(?, 150)` tells you this, since ? stands for variable size). And no, you cannot initialize a variable with changeable size, since tensorflow cannot allocate memory properly then.

Although you seem to strip the batch dimension when you ignore the first value of `shape_in`, there are two possibilities for this: the first is from the `size_out` parameter which you just pass through. The other is that you accidentally mixed up the dimensions in `shape_in` and do not actually strip the problem.

My recommendation is to run the code in a debugger - while you cannot track values in symbolic libraries such as tensorflow, you can easily see the shapes of the different variables.